# The panel function in widgets of wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm learning python gui.
As I code guiding by realpython.com

Here is the code:
[image]

My question:

Why `self` should be added in the `Panel()`?
Because object `panel`'s in `class'Myframe'`, so that `panel` could be used by `Myclass` when `panel = wx.Panel(self)`?

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Imagine a scenario where you wanted 2 panels inside the main panel, where you intend to place different widgets in each of them. Most widgets require a `parent`, your main panel uses, in this scenario `self`, which is in fact the `Frame`. In the imagined scenario, the `parent` of the 2 internal panels, would be the main panel `panel`.  All widgets need a place to call home!